# Angular2 not sending HTTP GET

Tags: http, angular

The code listed in (A) never sends its HTTP request when `test()` is called whereas the almost identical code in (B) does work.  Any idea what the problem is?  I know whether the request is sent by watching the server logs.  Also, if I make the request in (A) manually by pasting it into the browser, I get the expected response.  I'm stumped!

(A)

```
import { Constants } from '../toplevel/constants'

import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class SigninService {

  constructor (private http: Http, private constants : Constants) {

  }

  getToken(username: string, password: string) : Observable<string>{

    var url = `${this.constants.apiRoot}/users/${username}?${password}`

    console.log(`Calling api server with url ${url}`)

    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((res:Response) => JSON.stringify(res.json()))
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

  }

 test() {

   this.getToken('jc', 'yadayada')
 }
}
```

(B: excerpt)

```
getDocument(id: string) : Observable<Document>{
  return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/documents/${id}`)
  .map((res:Response) => new Document(res.json()['document']))
  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

  }
```

Comment: Also, I do see the messages posted by `console.log`

Comment: From the (A) code, you have an error code or something ? Could you try to add `.subscribe()` next to your catch to see ?

Comment: Have you use debugger; in your function to see what is happening step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence is cold. You need to change your test to:

```
   this.getToken('jc', 'yadayada').subscribe()
```

to make it active and send the request